# Загрузка текстур в OpenGL из SDL_image version 2.0

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, текстура

Сабж: Как загружать текстуру из SDL_image **версии 2.0** формата PNG или любого другого формата отличающего от bitmap ?!

P.S c BMP всё просто `SDL_LoadBMP( "KillaKill.bmp" )` а вот с PNG или с другими форматами

```
                                                                         /*BITMAP*/
    int LoadGLTextures( )
{
    /* Status indicator */
    int Status = false;

    /* Create storage space for the texture */
    SDL_Surface *TextureImage[1];

    // Load The Bitmap, Check For Errors, If Bitmap's Not Found Quit
    if ( ( TextureImage[0] = SDL_LoadBMP( "KillaKill.bmp" ) ) )

{
        /* Set the status to true */
        Status = true;

        /* Create The Texture */
        glGenTextures( 1, &Texture[0]);

        /* Typical Texture Generation Using Data From The Bitmap */
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture[0]);

        /* Generate The Texture */
        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, TextureImage[0]->w,
              TextureImage[0]->h, 0, GL_BGR,
              GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, TextureImage[0]->pixels );

        /* Linear Filtering */
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
        }

    // Free up any memory we may have used
    if ( TextureImage[0] )
        SDL_FreeSurface( TextureImage[0] );

    return Status;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int LoadGLTextures( )
{
    /* Status indicator */
    int Status = false;

    /* Create storage space for the texture */
    SDL_Surface *TextureImage[1];

    // Load The Bitmap, Check For Errors, If Bitmap's Not Found Quit

    /*if ( ( TextureImage[0] = SDL_LoadBMP( "KillaKill.bmp" ) ) )*/

    if ( ( TextureImage[0] = IMG_Load( "image.png" ) ) )
{
        /* Set the status to true */
        Status = true;

        /* Create The Texture */
        glGenTextures( 1, &Texture[0]);

        /* Typical Texture Generation Using Data From The Bitmap */
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture[0]);

        /* Generate The Texture */
        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, TextureImage[0]->w,
              TextureImage[0]->h, 0, GL_RGBA,
              GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, TextureImage[0]->pixels );

        /* Linear Filtering */
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
        }

    // Free up any memory we may have used
    if ( TextureImage[0] )
        SDL_FreeSurface( TextureImage[0] );

    return Status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

С sdl2_image просто:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL2_image.h> // Или где она там?

...
SDL_Surface *TextureImage = IMG_Load("image.png");
...
```

Функция `IMG_Load` принимает много форматов, такие как png, jpeg и другие.

Comment: Хорошо а есть ли полный код текстурного  коннвеера и кокой формат пикселей выбирать при построение т.к при BitMap использовались не совсем стандартные GL_BGR

Comment: Все тоже самое. Вот видео-туториал по этой теме: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNZZnp8r6qU

Comment: А вот пример кода: http://trickpixelgames.tk/tutorials/sdlgl/part2.cpp

Comment: Пытаюсь так но не получается в чём проблема ?! http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=effuCGcY

Comment: Проблема решилась использую тот же код надо подключить библиотеку SDL2_image и формат GL_RGBA